# Objective-C blocks to Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am using DZNPhotoPickerController which is written in Objective-C.

There are codes here that I can't convert to Swift.

```
//THIS CODES ARE ALREADY IN SWIFT AND ARE WORKING FINE
DZNPhotoPickerController *picker = [DZNPhotoPickerController new];
picker.supportedServices = DZNPhotoPickerControllerService500px | DZNPhotoPickerControllerServiceFlickr | DZNPhotoPickerControllerServiceGoogleImages;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.cropMode = DZNPhotoEditorViewControllerCropModeCircular;
picker.initialSearchTerm = @"California";
picker.enablePhotoDownload = YES;
picker.allowAutoCompletedSearch = YES;
//THIS CODES ARE ALREADY IN SWIFT AND ARE WORKING FINE


//HERE----------------------------
[picker setFinalizationBlock:^(DZNPhotoPickerController *picker, NSDictionary *info){
    //some codes
}];

[picker setFailureBlock:^(DZNPhotoPickerController *picker, NSError *error){
    //some codes
}];

picker.cancellationBlock = ^(DZNPhotoPickerController *picker){
    //some codes
};
//HERE----------------------------
```

Can anyone transform the codes to Swift?

Comment: Wow! seems someone is expecting that Stack Overflow will serve as an interpreter from Objective C to Swift!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't a programming language converter.

Comment: Answering strictly your question: "Can anyone transform the codes to Swift?" — yes, there are people who can transform this "codes" to Swift.

Comment: Wow people? Really? I was just asking for help here, I have been trying to figure out this code for HOURS. And I thought good people in this site can help me. Seems I was wrong. THANKS guys for being helpful and kind. You are then best examples of what humans are.

Comment: Can't believe how much negativity I receive for this question. I was thinking that this site is for "people who knows better helping the newer ones". But no, this is just all about getting the points. You wouldn't even help if there were no points nor badges right? If I was the better one I won't hesitate to help people having this problem. But at least ONE GUY DID AND HE GOT A DOWN VOTE. REALLY? When was helping negative. But thanks for all your negativity and sarcasm today. Keep that up.

Comment: Us doing your work isn't helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll help you with closures as I expect they are the most hard part of the code. Rest of the stuff is pretty similar to Java and other OOP languages.
You can check closure syntax [here](http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com). Correct me if my syntax is wrong:

```
    picker.finalizationBlock = {(picker, info) in
        //Your code here...
    }
    picker.failureBlock = {(picker, error) in
        //Your code here...
    }
    picker.cancellationBlock = {(picker) in
        //Your code here...
    }
```

Comment: Man, I can't thank you enough. I'm new with Swift and can't figure out this one. THANK YOU SO MUCH! At least someone here is not that bad at all. I owe you one.